# How is it possible to full screen screen share using getDisplayMedia without focus?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webrtc

I am implementing a screen sharing service using webrtc and getDisplayMedia. Could you explain how this is possible when the tab will no doubt lose focus? I am trying to share the display of some application or the entire screen itself.

It seems that unless I am sharing the tab that created the screen sharing, screen sharing always freezes streaming.

I'm using chrome 117.0.5938.152 on windows 11

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't stops sharing when I unfocused tab on Edge, and I think it must work on Chrome too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Screen Sharing Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Screen Sharing Example</h1>
    <button id="startButton">Start Screen Sharing</button>
    <video id="screenShare" autoplay controls></video>
    
    <script>
        const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');
        const screenShareVideo = document.getElementById('screenShare');

        startButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: { mediaSource: 'screen' } });
                screenShareVideo.srcObject = stream;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing screen sharing:', error);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```